# Why does entering "Î" to a Scanner result in the wrong character?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

When I do

```
String message="Î"
```

and take the numeric value of the first character with :

```
int x=message.charAt(0);
```

The output is 206, which is correct. However, if I input `Î` to a Scanner, like this:

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
String message=in.next(); // typing Î
```

the numeric value of the first character, as returned by:

```
int x=message.charAt(0);
```

is now 65533, which is wrong.

This is the full code:

```
System.out.println("Insert string here:");
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
String s=in.next();
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    System.out.println("Codice carattere:"+(int) s.charAt(i));
}
```

which outputs the wrong 65533 when inputting `Î`, and this is the full code:

```
String s="Î";   
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    System.out.println("Codice carattere:"+(int) s.charAt(i));
}
```

which outputs the right 206.

How can I make it work with `Scanner`?

Comment: Do you think another human being can really understand your problem from what you wrote?

Comment: He is wondering why the numeric value of `Î` differs when the character is read by the scanner and stored into a string, instead of having the string with the character from the beginning. Well, post a [mcve] and we shall see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value 65533 is 0xFFFD. This is the Unicode "Replacement Character" which is used in place of a character that is unrepresentable. It is normally displayed as "�". The reason you are getting this could be because your standard input (keyboard?) is not capable of producing the character "Î". Try putting this character into a text file instead, and then redirect the text file into standard input. (Make sure the text file does not start with a Byte Order Mark, which is what happens if you use Windows Notepad.)